# What do I convert a Delphi Win32 resource DLL to for a Delphi macOS app?

Tags: macos, delphi, dll, delphi-xe7

I have a resource DLL for a Windows Delphi app.  I want to port this to macOS, and eventually to iOS (for iPad only, not iPhone). I have yet to dip my toes into developing outside of the VCL (I don't even own a Mac yet, though I know I will need one eventually). The FireMonkey stuff, no problem (yet). I just wonder what approach to take to port a Windows resource DLL to other platforms.

Comment: What kind of resources are stored in the DLL?  Have you looked at the IDE's [Resources and Images](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Resources) dialog yet? If you are dealing with resource strings, have you tried using Delphi's built-in [`resourcestring`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Resourcestring) keyword yet? For other types of resources, you generally should use the [Deployment Manager](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Deployment_Manager) instead on non-Windows platforms.

Comment: In this case my resources are image files. I will look into the Resources and Images dialog. Never used it before. resourcestring - of course I've used that for years and years. However, Deployment Manager & Resources is a new one for me - thanks.

Comment: why the downvote on the question?

Comment: I'm not sure what the deal is with the snarky remark but I can assure you the question is reasonable, for me anyway. I have used resource DLLs for images in the past and this was very standard approach for Windows. I was simply wondering if there was an equivalent for macOS and iOS. As I don’t develop in Delphi as much I used to and I don’t yet have Mac or an iPad. As this is exploratory, I thought I’d ask a question or two, hopefully without being downvoted without explanation and getting a snarky remark. Just sayin…

Answer (score 1):

For Firemonkey, you can user the dialog box in menu "Project / Resource and images".

This help page will give you code sample to use it in your program :
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Resource_Files_Support